# How to get a cookie from an AJAX response?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome

I have a `$.ajax` request on the same domain and I want to read the cookie. It keeps returning `null`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: myUrl,
    success: function(output, status, xhr) {
        alert(xhr.getResponseHeader("MyCookie"));
    },
    cache: false
});
```

Any ideas? I'm using Chrome for this.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You're looking for a response header of `Set-Cookie`:

```
xhr.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie');
```

It won't work with HTTPOnly cookies though.

#### Update

According to the [XMLHttpRequest Level 1](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/default/xhr-1/Overview.html#the-getresponseheader()-method) and [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name), this particular response headers falls under the "forbidden" response headers that you can obtain using `getResponseHeader()`, so the only reason why this could work is basically a "naughty" browser.

Comment: Is there a way to instruct my browser to append the new cookies to my form?

Comment: If you send another request, those cookies wold be sent again. But since they're just strings you can add them as hidden fields I suppose.

Comment: I get null for the cookie. But in browser console I can see the response header of the file I did ajax to and cookie string as well. Any ideas? :/

Comment: I says 'Refused to get unsafe header "Set-Cookie"'

Comment: I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: It's not an HTTPOnly restriction. XHR has a list of forbidden headers, among which is the response header `Set-Cookie`. Here's the list https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name

Comment: @KonstantinosFilios Thanks, I've considered updating the answer for a while, but it has now happened :)

Comment: see @MrE answer's that works for the proper way to do this.

Comment: The list of forbidden response headers is https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name

Answer (score 55):

The **browser** cannot give access to 3rd party cookies like those received from ajax requests for security reasons, **however** it takes care of those automatically for you!

For this to work you need to:

**1) login with the ajax request from which you expect cookies to be returned:**

```
$.ajax("https://example.com/v2/login", {
     method: 'POST',
     data: {login_id: user, password: password},
     crossDomain: true,
     success: login_success,
     error: login_error
  });
```

**2) Connect with `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` in the next ajax request(s) to use the credentials saved by the browser**

```
$.ajax("https://example.com/v2/whatever", {
     method: 'GET',
     xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
     crossDomain: true,
     success: whatever_success,
     error: whatever_error
  });
```

The browser takes care of these cookies for you even though they are not readable from the `headers` nor the `document.cookie`

Comment: I have an sso server. I have two sso client apps. In app1 I login and it returns a cookie that is set for the sso server domain in my browser.

Now on subsequent ajax requests to sso server both the client apps attach this cookie successfully.

In app2 though the cookie returned from the ajax response is not set in the browser and it is not attached on subsequent calls to sso server.

Quite strange, can you please give some helpful hint?

Comment: I was not using this xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
     crossDomain: true, on the first ajax call. Its needed on first ajax call too to set the cookie in browser successfully. Once I did that, it worked successfully.

Comment: +10 This was super useful for building out a bot to monitor and automate a third party vendor site!

Answer (score 3):

```
xhr.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie');
```

It won't work for me.

I use this

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
} 

success: function(output, status, xhr) {
    alert(getCookie("MyCookie"));
},
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: I wonder who ever got in mind to downvote this answer. header 'Set-Cookie' may be absent in lots of cases; document.cookie is the safe way to go.

Comment: document.cookie is available on the document, not the XMLHttpRequest response.

Comment: this doedn't work: the type of cookie we are talking about are not available through code directly. you need to use xhrFields: {withCredentials: true} to request the browser to pass them back on for you.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to yebmouxing I could not the

```
 xhr.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie');
```

method to work. It would only return null even if I had set HTTPOnly to false on my server.

I too wrote a simple js helper function to grab the cookies from the document. This function is very basic and only works if you know the additional info (lifespan, domain, path, etc. etc.) to add yourself:

```
function getCookie(cookieName){
  var cookieArray = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0; i<cookieArray.length; i++){
    var cookie = cookieArray[i];
    while (cookie.charAt(0)==' '){
      cookie = cookie.substring(1);
    }
    cookieHalves = cookie.split('=');
    if(cookieHalves[0]== cookieName){
      return cookieHalves[1];
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```