# Secure way to send password cross domain

Tags: jquery, wcf, security, authentication, cross-domain

I'm trying to implement the same client side login system on multiple websites all sending a cross domain request to the same server (.Net WCF).

The idea is to provide the same javascript on each website.

Anyway, POST request didn't work so I send GET request. But then all the parameters are in the url available to everyone. Even with https the urls can still be viewed.

Using a proxy is unfortunatly not possible so I'm sure what else to do.

Do you have any idea of how I could send the password more securly ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Passwords should ideally only be sent once, after which you work with (temporary) authentication tokens. And why is your server outside of the domain in the first place?

Comment: The password and email are only sent the first time, then I do use a temporary token. The server taking care of the login and the website must be completly independant. The idea was to make the same user accounts available on multiple websites which may be on an other server and maintenained by someone else.

Comment: Sounds like a job for OpenLDAP or Active directory....

Answer (score 0):

To be able to POST cross domain and read the response you need to implement [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Your server side code should check the `Origin` header in the HTTP request to check that the protocol and domain is one of your websites, and if so you need to return

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin>`
and
`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

as HTTP headers in the response. This will allow your script to read the response from the other domain. You should then be able to [read the cookie in the response header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12840533/413180) if necessary, or if all session information is retrieved from the remote domain then you can simply make additional AJAX requests to retrieve the data you need.