# Get and store cookie (from Set-Cookie) from an AJAX POST response

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, http-headers, httpresponse

I have a simple jQuery AJAX POST code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: AppConstants.URLs.PROXY,
    data: message,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log("Cookie: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"));
    }
});
```

and I wish to get the cookie and save it using [cookies-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-js).

But according to http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getallresponseheaders%28%29-method:

> 3. Return all response headers, **excluding headers that are a case-insensitive match for Set-Cookie or Set-Cookie2**, as a single string, with each header line separated by a U+000D CR U+000A LF pair, excluding the status line, and with each header name and header value separated by a U+003A COLON U+0020 SPACE pair.

Using the Network tool in Chrome, "Set-Cookie" is visible in the Response headers. I also verified that the "Set-Cookie" header appears using `curl`.

What do I have to do to save the cookie in my front end app? Also, my app is running on **https** only.

I'd gladly provide more details upon request.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't get the cookie data in your JS. The API won't allow you.

> What do I have to do to save the cookie in my front end app?

Just set the `Set-Cookie` header in the response from the server side code. The browser should save it automatically.

As a developer, you may be able to inspect the value of the cookies using "Developer Tools".

And the same cookie will be sent in subsequent requests to the same domain, until the cookie expires.

Comment: How do I access it? `document.cookie` returns undefined or empty string when logged.

Comment: You don't access it with JS at all. The browser stores it transparently. The server accesses it as normal.

Comment: So it will always be included in all of my future AJAX requests?

Comment: This is only true if `HttpOnly`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Comment: @M3D — No. `HttpOnly` determines if cookies **for the HTML document the JS is running inside** are accessible via [the `document.cookie` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie). It has no effect on cookies set in response to an Ajax request which are always unavailable, and no effect on if a cookie is stored by the browser or not (which is what the question is asking about).

Answer (score 9):

The **browser** cannot give access to 3rd party cookies like those received from ajax requests for security reasons, **however** it takes care of those automatically for you!

For this to work you need to:

**1) login with the ajax request from which you expect cookies to be returned:**

```
$.ajax("https://example.com/v2/login", {
     method: 'POST',
     data: {login_id: user, password: password},
     crossDomain: true,
     success: login_success,
     error: login_error
  });
```

**2) Connect with `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` in the next ajax request(s) to use the credentials saved by the browser**

```
$.ajax("https://example.com/v2/whatever", {
     method: 'GET',
     xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
     crossDomain: true,
     success: whatever_success,
     error: whatever_error
  });
```

The browser takes care of these cookies for you even though they are not readable from the `headers` nor the `document.cookie`

see my answer here: [How to get a cookie from an AJAX response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840410/how-to-get-a-cookie-from-an-ajax-response/37955635#37955635)