# Set-cookies are not stored

Tags: reactjs, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a problem with the cookies sent by my API server. I use React app as a frontend and a PHP backend server, they have different domains. The flow is like this: A user logs in and the frontend sends and XMLHTTPRequest with "withCredentials" set true to the backend server, the backend server then responds with this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 04 May 2018 02:37:01 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-CSRF-TOKEN
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://frontend.com
Message: Successfully logged in.
Set-Cookie: cookie-token1=; HttpOnly; Path=/; Domain=frontend.com
Set-Cookie: cookie-token2; Path=/; Domain=frontend.com
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Although the backend responds with cookies, the cookies are not stored in the browser. I added Allow-Credentials and Allow-Origin headers to the server response so the cookies are acknowledged by the browser, but the cookies ares still not stored. Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: I guess this problem related to your backend server.

Comment: Does this mean I&#39;m missing a header or something? I forgot to mention that the cookie storing works when I use localhost:3000 as frontend and localhost:8000 as my backend.

Comment: How are you verifying that cookies are not stored?

Comment: Document.cookies returns empty steing when I call it and I also checked the cookie storage on console, my cookies are not stored.

Comment: that is the trick, you can't read cookies from another domain but if you review in developer tools, cookies should appear

Comment: But doesn't Allow-credentials and Allow-origin make that possible?

Comment: I think it is the same that this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29895984/2012487

Comment: Ok, I forgot to mention that the cookies are not listed on the cookies section of storage tab on developer tools. I'll still try to make something out of the link you gave, thanks.