# can get the cookies set by django in the response of ajax request

Tags: ajax, django, axios, django-cors-headers

cors-headers to enable the cors on my django server. my `setting.py` is like this.

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL= True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

also i have added `corsheaders` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` and my `MIDDLEWARE` is like this

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
```

].
i have set a very simple view that looks like this.

```
    def get(self, request):

    response = HttpResponse("hi")
    response['Set-Cookie'] = ('food=bread; Path=/; max_age=10000')
    print(response._headers)
    return response
```

on the console the headers is like this.

```
{'set-cookie': ('Set-Cookie', 'food=bread; drink=water; Path=/; max_age=10000'), 'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')}
```

when i call my api in browser cookie is set and everything is ok but when i use axios for ajax in the body of response there is nothing that is similar to my cookie.
my javasctipt code i like this.

```
 axios.get('http://37.130.202.188:13434/users/test/',
  {withCredentials: true,

 })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

and i run my server with this command

```
python manage.py runserver
```

every response to this headache would be very appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem, but you should consider using [`Response.set_cookie()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie) instead of generating the cookie header yourself.

Comment: @solarissmoke i have tested that way but it doesn't work.

Comment: @solarissmoke when i hit the url by my browser everything is fine but i dont get cookies set in ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer. Exactly like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895569/get-and-store-cookie-from-set-cookie-from-an-ajax-post-response), the cookies that are set in the headers of a http response are not accessible in Javascript and they get saved in the browser automatically.