# Django session not available on two seperate requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

**Description:**

In the [django session docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/) it says:

> You can read it and write to request.session at any point in your view.

But I can't access the session when making a second request to the same view:

views.py

```py
class Login(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        print("before: ", request.session.get("user")
        request.session["user"] = "admin"
        print(request.session.get("user")) #outputs 'admin'
        return Response()
```

**Expected Output:**

After the second request (made with [jquery $.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)) it should output:

```
"admin"
```

**Output:**

Instead it outputs:

```
None
```

How can I make sessions available between independend requests?

Comment: Show how you make the requests from the client. You are likely _not_ using a session at the client and making each request independently.

Comment: Shouldn't sessions be stored in the backend for security reasons?

Comment: I use jquery to make a post/get request to the URLs

Comment: The session data can be stored in the database or the cookies depending on what you set. But at least the _session key_ needs to be in the cookies.

Comment: So I need to return the session key from the Login view and send it in every request to the Files view?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895569/get-and-store-cookie-from-set-cookie-from-an-ajax-post-response The second answer to this question should help you I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @AbdulAzizBarkat in the comments, the problem was that the session credentials were not sent to the backend. The way the sessions work in a cross-domain scenario is:

- User is verified in backend
- Session is sent to the frontend and stored in the browser
- The session credentials have to get sent to the backend on every request

You cannot, however, read this session cookies, like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37955661/9947071):

> The browser cannot give access to 3rd party cookies like those received from ajax requests for security reasons, however it takes care of those automatically for you!

The provided solution using ajax and setting `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` did not work for me.

**Answer:**

Instead of an ajax request, I used [fetch requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

It is important to set `credentials: "include"` since otherwise cookies *won't be sent cross-origin*. A request looks like this:

```js
fetch(`${API}/login`, {
    credentials: "include",
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
}).then(...).catch(...);
```