# ng2 get csrf token from cookie post it as header

Tags: angular, cookies, csrf

After spending 2 full days searching the web and reading docs and tons of open questions of people facing the same problem, i still don't grasp how Angular 2 handles the (x-origin) cookies and how to access them.

**The problem:**
Back-end sends 2 cookies with x-csrf-token & JSESSIONID inside of it. My job is to keep the csrf token in memory (ng2) and send it (only) back as **header** (not cookie) with every post to the back-end.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
Set-Cookie: x-csrf-token=8555257a-396f-43ac-8587-c6d489e76026; Path=/app
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=73E38392C60370E38FBAF80143ECE212; Path=/app/; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 12 Apr 2018 07:49:02 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 12 Apr 2017 07:49:02 GMT
```

**My partial solution:**
I created a custom RequesstOptions class that extends the BaseRequestOptions. Added some extra headers, and set the 'withCredentials' as true.

```js
export class MyRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {

  headers: Headers = new Headers({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  });

  withCredentials = true;
}
```

In my HttpService i do the post and get like so:

```js
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(
    protected _http: Http,
    protected requestOptions: RequestOptions
  ) {  }

  get(url): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(url, this.requestOptions).map( res => res.json() );
  }

  post(url: string, object: any): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.post(url, object, this.requestOptions).map( res => res.json() );
  }
}
```

and in my app.module i do the magic like so:

```js
 providers: [
    { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: DocumentumDefaultRequestOptions },
    { provide: XSRFStrategy, useFactory: xsrfFactory }
  ],
```

my xsrfFactory

```js
export function xsrfFactory() {
  return new CookieXSRFStrategy('x-csrf-token', 'x-csrf-token');
}
```

**My partial result:** 
At this point angular sends a cookie with every request (GET and POST without discrimination) with the jsessionid and x-csrf-token like so:

```
POST /app/business-objects/business-objects-type HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8040
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 26
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Basic ZG1hZG1pbjphZG1pbg==
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:4200/page
Cookie: JSESSIONID=B874C9A170EFC12BEB0EDD4266896F2A; x-csrf-token=0717876e-f402-4a1c-a31a-2d60e48509d3
```

**My billion dollar questions:**

- How and where do i access the x-csrf-token, and how do i add it to my requests?
- What does `CookieXSRFStrategy('x-csrf-token', 'x-csrf-token');` exactly do. I don't like the blackbox feeling / understand the way the docs explained it. Can i access it for data ?

> Before sending an HTTP request, the CookieXSRFStrategy looks for a cookie called XSRF-TOKEN and sets a header named X-XSRF-TOKEN with the value of that cookie.

- It doesn't set the header in my case ... but why ?
- Right now i'm sending the cookie to the backend with the sessionid and the csrf token but what is sending it? The CookieXSRFStrategy or 'withCredentials' flag.

*Please don't answer with one liner like "document.cookie". Data is useless without its metadata*

Comment: Is the `x-csrf-token` cookie sent (by the backend) with the document or with ajax GET requests ?

Comment: what does `document.cookie` returns ?

Comment: @n00dl3 
Q1: The back-end sends the csrf token automatically with every get / post (regardless of its origin 'rest call' or by 'browser navigation') If the back-end sees valid session token as cookie in the request , it will omit that information in response

Q2: Please don't answer with one liner like "document.cookie".  If you want me to try something, say where and how i should implement it .

Comment: 1. this is not an answer, this is a comment, such an answer would be deleted anyway. 2.The comment you deleted "Have you read the question ?" is unconstructive and don't encourage people to help you. 3. Nobody here is your employee, I'm not paid to help you, neither is anyone out there "I don't understand where I should try this, could you elaborate ?" is much kinder than "If you want me to try something, say where and how i should implement it". [Be nice.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Update for angular 5.0+

`Http` service beign deprecated in favor of `HttpClient`, the `CookieXSRFStrategy` class has been deprecated too, now this mission is delegated to the `HttpClientXsrfModule` class. If you want to customize the header and cookie names, you just need to import this module like so :

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
      cookieName: 'My-Xsrf-Cookie',
      headerName: 'My-Xsrf-Header',
    }),
  ]
})
export class MyModule{}
```

## For future readers:

### Ajax response cookies

You cannot access any cookie from any Ajax response, if you check [the XHR spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name), you will notice that any access to a header matching "Set-Cookie" is forbidden :

> A forbidden response-header name is a header name that is a byte-case-insensitive match for one of:
>
> - `Set-Cookie`
> - `Set-Cookie2`

#### But my cookie isn't `httpOnly`

Good for you, but `httpOnly` only states that your cookie cannot be accessed via `document.cookie` (see further).

#### The `document.cookie` API

The only cookies you will be able to access with javascript is `document.cookie` but `document.cookie` refers to **the cookie that has been sent with the document** (the page your script is running on) and **won't get modified at any time**. MDN states clearly it refers to the current document:

> #### `Document.cookie`
>
> Get and set the cookies associated with the current document. For a general library see this simple cookie framework.

Source : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

*Any cookie set by an Ajax response does not belong to the current document.*

#### How do I implement my csrf protection, then ?

The [cookie to header token protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Cookie-to-Header_Token) is the way to go. Note that **the token you will send is the same during the whole session, and it is not suposed to change according to wild Ajax requests sending cookies**.

> Web applications that use JavaScript for the majority of their operations may use an anti-CSRF technique that relies on same-origin policy:

> - On login, the web application sets a cookie containing a random token that remains the same for the whole user session
>
>   ```
>     Set-Cookie: Csrf-token=i8XNjC4b8KVok4uw5RftR38Wgp2BFwql; expires=Thu, 23-Jul-2015 10:25:33 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
>   ```

> - JavaScript operating on the client side reads its value and copies it into a custom HTTP header sent with each transactional request
>
>   ```
>     X-Csrf-Token: i8XNjC4b8KVok4uw5RftR38Wgp2BFwql
>   ```
> - The server validates presence and integrity of the token

> Security of this technique is based on the assumption that only JavaScript running within the same origin will be able to read the cookie's value. JavaScript running from a rogue file or email will not be able to read it and copy into the custom header. Even though the csrf-token cookie will be automatically sent with the rogue request, the server will be still expecting a valid X-Csrf-Token header.

Source: [Wikipedia : CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Cookie-to-Header_Token)

With Angular 2+ this mission is fulfilled by the `CookieXSRFStrategy` class.

### Original answer

> How and where do i access the x-csrf-token, and how do i add it to my requests?

Using `CookieXSRFStrategy` seems to be the way to go to add it to your request. For the "how", unfortunately, the answer might be "you can't" (see further).

> What does CookieXSRFStrategy('x-csrf-token', 'x-csrf-token'); exactly do. I don't like the blackbox feeling / understand the way the docs explained it.

#### CookieXSRFStrategy

> ```js
> /**
>  * `XSRFConfiguration` sets up Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) protection for the application
>  * using a cookie. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)
>  * for more information on XSRF.
>  *
>  * Applications can configure custom cookie and header names by binding an instance of this class
>  * with different `cookieName` and `headerName` values. See the main HTTP documentation for more
>  * details.
>  *
>  * @experimental
>  */
> export class CookieXSRFStrategy implements XSRFStrategy {
>   constructor(
>       private _cookieName: string = 'XSRF-TOKEN', private _headerName: string = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN') {}
>
>   configureRequest(req: Request): void {
>     const xsrfToken = getDOM().getCookie(this._cookieName);
>     if (xsrfToken) {
>       req.headers.set(this._headerName, xsrfToken);
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.ts#L180-L203)

Basically, it reads the cookie from `document.cookie` and modify the `Request` headers accordingly.

> Right now i'm sending the cookie to the backend with the sessionid and the csrf token but what is sending it? The CookieXSRFStrategy or 'withCredentials' flag.

That's `withCredentials` flag, this flag indicates that the XHR should send all the cookies that have been sent (even those previously set by Ajax response, but **as cookies, not headers**, and there is no way to change this behavior)

> It doesn't set the header in my case ... but why ?

The cookie you are talking about is not sent with the document (`index.html`) but from another ajax request. The fact is you cannot access cookies set by ajax response ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840410/how-to-get-a-cookie-from-an-ajax-response#answer-12840533)), because that would be a security issue: a simple ajax get on `www.stackoverflow.com` from a random web page would get the stack overflow cookie, and an attacker could steal it easily (if an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header is present on stackoverflow response).

On the other hand, the `document.cookie` API can only access to the cookies that are set when the document has been loaded, not any other.

So you should rethink the flow of your client/server communication on the server-side, because the only cookie that you will be able to copy to the headers is the one that has been sent with the document your script is running on (index.html).

> it isn't a httpOnly cookie so it should be accessible with js even if it is X origin

`httpOnly` makes the cookie unavailable to the `document.cookie` API, **but** as I told you, `document.cookie` refers to the **cookie that has been sent with the document, not those sent via Ajax responses**. You can make thousands of ajax call with a `Set-Cookie` Header in the response, `document.cookie` will still be the same string, without any modification.

#### Billion dollar solution

The server should only send one `x-csrf-token` cookie containing the token with the document, and you should use that token that will be valid for the whole session for every request using `CookieXSRFStrategy`. Why ? because [that is how it works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Cookie-to-Header_Token).

Comment: Thank you for taking time
But what is wrong with the flow i'm trying to use ? I have a rest back-end and angular 2 as front app. The rest back-end expects a csrf token as header for every post request with a token. that token is in the cookie that i get from the same back-end. it isn't a httpOnly cookie so it should be accessible with js even if it is X origin

Comment: accessing `set-Cookie` header is forbidden in [XHR spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name). you can send the cookie back without modification (with `withCredentials` flag), but as the js can't read it, you cannot put it in a header. `httpOnly` makes the cookie not appear in `document.cookie` but `document.cookie` is only relevant for  cookies that have been sent **with the document** (index.html), not those set by Ajax responses.

Comment: @n00dl3 So, you should set the cookie on document (index.html)? Would the client get a new cookie each time index.html loads?

Comment: Yes, but in case of single page apps (like angular-ones), you only load it once.

Comment: Note that CookieXSRFStrategy is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, now it is `HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({ cookieName : "foo", headerName : "bar"})`. I'll edit tomorrow.

Comment: I believe the answer needs to be edited to say "withOptions" instead of "withConfig"

Comment: Thank you. This is one of the best explanations on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

**Angular has built in support for XSRF** see here: 
https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection

*"When performing HTTP requests, an interceptor reads a token from a cookie, by default XSRF-TOKEN, and sets it as an HTTP header, X-XSRF-TOKEN"*

So if your server sets a cookie named XSRF-TOKEN then **it will work automatically!** Nothing to do on the client side.
If you want to name your cookie/header something else then you can do that as well:

```
imports: [
  HttpClientModule,
  HttpClientXsrfModule.withConfig({
    cookieName: 'My-Xsrf-Cookie',
    headerName: 'My-Xsrf-Header',
  }),
]
```

AND if you are using spring security, it supports the angular naming conventions so you can configure this server side:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            ....
```

Comment: I'm using .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()) . But the problem is to me this just works for GET Requests... When i try to make a PUT, DELETE OR POST I receive a 403 error

Comment: I have the same problem that you @Andre and don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: @chavocarlos Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67320068/how-to-set-samesite-none-in-jsessionid-cookie