# Angular/Express CSRF approach

Tags: angular, express, csrf

**Context**: I’m using Angular 1.6 (served from s3) + Express.js (API), domain is the same, authentication is done via JWT token in Authorization header, almost all communication is via ajax/xmlhttp requests, no cookies are sent together with request/response, API is open for cross domain requests.

**Problem**: I need to add CSRF protection. 90% of API requests are ajax but I also have several places where I use regular HTTP POST call using …

**What I have learned till now**: If to be short ,what I got from a lot of articles is that first layer of defense against CSRF is setting up correct CORS, then I can also use double cookie check and finally Synchronize Token

**What I plan to do**: Add `GET /csrf` api route, call it on app start, store token in Redis for user:sessionId key, return it to client and use it as header for ajax requests and add it as a hidden field to s

**Question**: Is it a correct way of doing Synchronize Token type of defense? Does it make sense to add /csrf api endpoint if I haven’t configured CORS for the API? (it’s a bit complicated to configure CORS now since there are clients who use API from different domains)

Comment: Usually, the csrf cookie for single page app is sent with the index.html and does not deserve its own API endpoint. maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364213/ng2-get-csrf-token-from-cookie-post-it-as-header/43365939#43365939) will hep you.

Comment: @n00dl3, thank you, now I understand that I should follow cookie-to-header approach, but the only issue is that index.html is stored on AWS S3 bucket and is completely separate from API. So the only way I can get a token to the frontend is by receiving it via ajax call in the response body and put it in cookies on frontend. do you think this will work?

Comment: IMHO that endpoint is not a problem if you have no choice .

Comment: @n00dl3 ok, thank you