# NGINX proxy not setting session cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, vue.js, nginx, nuxt.js

I have a Rails app as an API and a Nuxt.js (Vue.js) app as a frontend client.

I'm currently serving them locally. Rails runs on port `3000` and Nuxt.js runs on port `4000`

Have the my `/etc/hosts` setup to the domain name: `api.todos.test` for Rails and `todos.test` for Nuxt.js

My NGINX configs are:

```
upstream rails_api {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.todos.test;

    location ~ ^/rest/ {
        proxy_pass http://rails_api;
        proxy_set_header Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header NginX-Proxy   true;
        proxy_set_header Host          $subdomain.todos.test:3000;
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://todos.test:4000;
        proxy_set_header Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Host        $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I am able to hit both servers, so NGINX is handling the proxying. My Rails API returns a response with `Set-Cookie: _session_id=...` but for some reason this never gets set in Chrome.

Am I doing something wrong in NGINX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems when using NGINX (or perhaps any reverse proxy), it's necessary to set the `domain` in the cookie when sending it from the server.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Been looking for this answer for quite a while! Added Domain and everything started to work. I'm using Nginx Proxy Manager so hopefully, by including those words, more people with problem will find this answer lot quicker than me.

Comment: Had this issue with phpmyadmin container behind nginx.  while it's true you need to set `proxy_set_header` you also need to make sure `PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI` is set in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Are you send XHR request to that Rails API?

The browser cannot give access to 3rd party cookies like those received from ajax requests for security reasons.

You can get/set the cookie manually.
Please refer this question.
[How to get a cookie from an AJAX response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840410/how-to-get-a-cookie-from-an-ajax-response)

Comment: The session cookie is httpOnly. I discovered the issue. Will post soon.